# Windows Phone 8.1 Monogame Content.Load<Effect> exception

Tags: xna, directx, monogame, effects

need some help, just trying to load compiled .fx (.xnb) file by monogame (version 3.4.0.456) in Windows **Phone** 8.1 enviroment by this code

```
MainEffect = Game.Content.Load<Effect>("chessboard");
```

there is a some delay, about 3-4 seconds, and then i get

> SharpDX.SharpDXException 
>   "Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: The parameter is incorrect."

Tried different files, but seems no matter how complex the are, behaviour is the same.
Even this simple effect gives an error:

```
float4x4 World;

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;
    output.Position = mul(input.Position, World);
    output.Color = input.Color;
    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    return input.Color;
}

technique Specular
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile  vs_4_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

But for Windows 7/8/10 its works well. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Well changed versions of vs/ps to 4_0_level_9_3 and it worked :)

```
    VertexShader = compile vs_4_0_level_9_3 VertexShaderFunction();
    PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_3 PixelShaderFunction();
```